# Problem with height of floating divs

Tags: css, css-float

I need to put two divs side by side. First div should have constant width, second take rest free space. Both of the div should has the same height but at least should takes all browser screen. I have written the following code:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>My Testing page</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    #mainDiv { height:100%;}
    #leftDiv {float:left; width:200px; height:100%;}
    #rightDiv { height:100%; } 
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="mainDiv">
      <div id="leftDiv"></div>
  <div id="rightDiv"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

But height of the right div is always set to 100% of browser screen, Even if content of this div is bigger. I would like have resizable height of those divs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `height:100%` would act as a fixed height according to the browser's height.
 so why dont you put

`min-height:100%`.

This should work but I havent tested it myself tbh.

Comment: you could always use javascript to get the height of the page in px, use that as min-height value instead of percentage.